# Java How to Remove Double-Quote Character Between Double Quote Text Qualifier

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file where each field (except column headings) has a double quote text qualifier: field: `"some value"`. However some of the fields in the file have a double quote within the value; field2: `"25" TV"` or field3: `"25" x 14" x 2""` or field4: `"A"bcd"ef"g"`. (I think you get the point). In cases where I have data like in fields 2-4, my java file process fails due to me specifying that the double-quote is a text-qualifier on the fields and it looks as if there are too many fields for that row. How do I do either or all of the following:

- remove the double-quote character from inside the field
- replace the double-quote character with another value
- have my java process "ignore" or "skip" double-quotes within a field.

What is my level of control over this file? The file comes in as-is, but I just need data from two different columns in the file. I can do whatever I need to do to it to get that data.

Comment: Option 4 - Stop generating invalid CSVs to begin with

Comment: @SeanBright like I said, the file comes in as-is. So I have to work with what I got.

Comment: Are the following always true? 1) None of the columns in the header have quotes and 2) All of the columns in the data rows do have quotes?

Comment: Can you just take a substring? If you can guarantee that the name comes with a starting and end quote, this would be the fastest option.

Comment: @SeanBright 1) Yes, 2) Yes.

Comment: @JClassic How would I do that? when I read the file and specify the text-qualifier The double-quotes would be removed at that point.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here. Are you parsing the csv manually? I'm assuming if the file is inherently invalid CSV, no library is going to support it?

Comment: OP wants to "fix" the invalid data before parsing it with a traditional CSV parser. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: @JClassic I am using a java managed file transfer tool to read the file.

Answer (score 1):

First, if it is indeed a CSV file, you should be using the presence of commas to break each line into columns.

Once its broken in columns, if we know for sure that the value should begin and end with double-quote ("), we can simply remove all of the double-quote and then re-apply the ones at the beginning and end.

```
    String input = "\"hello\",\"goodbye Java \"the best\" language\", \"this is really \"\"\"bad\"";
    String[] parsed = input.split(",");
    String[] clean = new String[parsed.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (String value : parsed) {
        clean[index] = "\"" + value.replace("\"", "") + "\"";
        index++;
    }
```

If a comma could exist inside of the value, the following should be used instead

```
    String input = "\"hello\",\"goodbye,\" Java \"the best\" language\", \"this is really \"\"\"bad\"";
    String[] parsed = input.split("\"\\s*,\\s*\"");
    String[] clean = new String[parsed.length];
    int index = 0;
    for (String value : parsed) {
        clean[index] = "\"" + value.replace("\"", "") + "\"";
        index++;
    }
}
```

Note that if the sequence of \"\s*,\s*\" existed inside a value, the record would be ambiguous. For example, if it was a two column file, the input record
"abc","def","ghi" could be either

value 1 = "abc","def" value 2 = "ghi"
or
value 1 = "abc" value 2 = "def","ghi"

Comment: What if the internal quote is followed by a comma?

Comment: @SeanBright - if commas are allowed inside a value then there would be some records that would indeed be ambiguous.  For example, if there were only two columns, how would we parse "abc","def","hig", is the first value "abc" and the second "def","hig", or is the first "abc","def" and the second "hig"?

Answer (score 0):

Note many CSV implementations will escape a double quote as two consecutive quotes.

So `"25"" TV"` might (should?) be your input.

Comment: The question says they have no control over the file format :P

Comment: Then its not really CSV.

Comment: Here is a state-machine based CSV parser I wrote a long time ago. The state remembers if it saw a quote or comma and might do the right thing.  Sorry, limited doc. https://github.com/bswieser/omdi/blob/master/util/CSVParser.java

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a comma is the column separator and that every column is surrounded by double quotes:

```
String[] columns = input.split("\",\"");
if (columns.length > 0) {
  columns[0] = columns[0].substring(1);
  String lastColumn = columns[columns.length-1];
  columns[columns.length-1] = lastColumn.substring(0,lastColumn.length()-1);
}
```

The columns will still have the internal double quotes. You can replace them out if you don't want them.